# Check if position exists

Tags: jquery

I have a page with elements, with relative position.

```
style="position: relative;"
```

Some have top/left coordinates and some don't. Is there a way to check of the coordinates exist inside the style tag with jQuery?

If not, I'd like to add them by doing something like:

```
if (...) {
    var myDiv = $(".myDiv");    
    var pos = myDiv.position();
    myDiv.css({ "left:" + pos.left + "px", "top:" + pos.top + "px" });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As demonstrated by [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CpTnn/) the default value of top/left is "*auto*". So to check if the CSS value is set or not, you can check whether the value is "*auto*" or not.

---

The test:

```
<div style="position: relative;"></div>

<div style="position: relative; left: 10px;"></div>

<div style="position: relative; left: badvalue;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('div').each(function() {
            alert($(this).css('left'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Cool! So, I can do something like this: if (myDiv.css('left') == 'auto') {
  var pos = myDiv.position();
  myDiv.css({ "left:" + pos.left + "px", "top:" + pos.top + "px" });
 }

Comment: You should read the documentation on [jQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) as the code in your above comment is incorrect. But other than that, yes I don't see why not :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `css` method:

```
var hasTop = $('#element').css('top') !== 'auto';
var hasLeft = $('#element').css('left') !== 'auto';
```

The default value for `top` and `left` is `auto`, so if the `css` method doesn't return that you know the style attributes have been set elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check for those style declaration like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/E5V7f/1/)

HTML:

```
<span style="position: relative;"></span>
<span style="position: relative; top: 100px; "></span>
<span style="position: relative;"></span>
<span style="position: relative; left: 10px;"></span>
<span style="position: relative;"></span>
```

JS

```
$('span').each (function () {
    alert(this.style.left != '' || this.style.top != '');
});
```